# No resource with given url found error while using Ajax in vb.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, vb.net

i have a function 'QAjax' called on button click 'btnsave_Click' inside that button click i am calling function 'QAjax' but geting error at url  "No resource with given url found error"

```
Protected Sub btnsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(UI.Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "QAjax();", True)
End Sub


function QAjax() {            
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ENTRY.aspx/irix",
        data: { colv: colv, rowv: rowv }, 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("yes");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
        
    });
        }

 Protected Sub irix(colv As String, rowv As String)
Dim abc As String =colv
Dim def As String =rowv
End Sub
```

Where is the error exactly i am not able to rectify any idea would be appreciated

Comment: looks like you have vb code and js code mixed together there, not sure at all what you're doing

Comment: Well he is calling a javascript file from vba, not so hard to understand when you read the first function

Comment: The question is what exactly are you trying to achieve? Because `ENTRY.aspx/irix` is indeed not a valid url